# How do I prove $\operatorname{div} (f \nabla g) = f\Delta g + \nabla f \cdot\nabla g$?

Tags: greens-function, greens-relations

Let $f\in C^1$ and $g\in C^2$ be scalar functions. How do I prove the identity

$$\operatorname{div} (f \nabla g) = f\Delta g + \nabla f \cdot\nabla g$$

?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Do you have any difficulties in calculating each term in terms of partial derivatives by definition?

Comment: Im lost...Rlly dunno wat to do

Comment: The divergence admits a product rule. Index notation will help here,
$$\operatorname{div}(f\nabla g)=\nabla_j (f \nabla^j g)$$

Answer (score -1):

It's all just a matter of plugging things into the definitions. Recall the following definitions:

$$\operatorname{div}(F)=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_jF_j,$$

$$\nabla G=(\partial_1 G,\dots,\partial_n G),$$

$$\Delta G=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_j^2G,$$

$$\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n x_jy_j.$$

The left hand side then becomes

$$\operatorname{div}(f\cdot\nabla g)=\operatorname{div}(f\cdot\partial_1g,\dots,f\cdot\partial_ng)=\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_j(f\cdot\partial_jg)=\sum_{j=1}^n\bigl(\partial_jf\cdot\partial_jg+f\cdot\partial_j^2g\bigr).$$

One the other hand we can compute the right hand side as

$$f\cdot\Delta g+\langle \nabla f,\nabla g\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^nf\cdot\partial_j^2g+\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_jf\cdot\partial_jg=\sum_{j=1}^n\bigl(\partial_jf\cdot\partial_jg+f\cdot\partial_j^2g\bigr).$$

Now both computations gave us the same thing, and so $\operatorname{div}(f\cdot\nabla g)=f\cdot\Delta g+\langle \nabla f,\nabla g\rangle$, as was desired.

Comment: I dont have words to describe, just thank you